# AM-GM Inequality Problem involving Factorial

Tags: inequality

Problem: Prove that $\sqrt{n}\le (n!)^{1/n}$ for every positive integer $n$.
I know that the AM-GM inequality is involved in this but I don't exactly see how. However, I do see that $(n!)^{1/n}\le \dfrac{n+1}2$ and $\sqrt{n}\le\dfrac{n+1}2$ by AM-GM. But I can't seem to relate the left hand sides of both these inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AM-GM might as well be kept out of this, since it is busy at work in so many other places. Note that 
$$(n!)^2=[1\cdot n][2\cdot (n-1)](3\cdot (n-2)]\cdots [n\cdot 1].$$
This is a  trick related to the one said to have been used by little  Gauss.

Also, if $k$ is an integer with $1\le k\le n$ then $k\cdot(n+1-k)\ge n$. 
It follows that 
$$(n!)^2 \ge n^n,$$
which is basically the result we are after.

Comment: Thanks, and do you mean to say k*(n+1-k)>= n?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how that typo snuck in.